# Find out is ephemeral disk in AWS ec2 servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services

All,

How to find out is the disk is ephemeral disk type. I could not find the options to find out 
ephemeral disk in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this ?  They are called `Instance Store`. You need to use an m1.small or larger intance. t1.micro instances don't support ephemeral storage.

[image]